# Android kernel BUG at drivers/gpu/msm/adreno_dispatch.c

Tags: android, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, android-hardware, qualcomm

OnePlus 7T smartphone randomly freezes and rebooting.

Bootloader unlocked and rooted. Smartphone runs on Android 11, but the same behavior occurred on a purely installed Android 12. Often the error appears in moments related to graphics, such as rotating the screen, changing the screen in games (the appearance of a video screensaver, for example). This can happen from once a day to several times.

From the logs it is clear that this is somehow related to video drivers:

```
[20240305_12:19:40.412080]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: GMU CM3 fault interrupt received
[20240305_12:19:40.512637]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: OOB_set(0x40000000) timed out
[20240305_12:19:40.622730]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: ----------------------[ GMU error ]----------------------
[20240305_12:19:40.622782]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: Timeout waiting for lowest idle level 3
[20240305_12:19:40.622804]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: Timestamps: 272b38cc6 272d3aee0 272d3af12
[20240305_12:19:40.622825]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: RPMH_POWER_STATE=0 SPTPRAC_PWR_CLK_STATUS=0
[20240305_12:19:40.622846]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: CX_BUSY_STATUS=71000000 CP_STATUS_1=1000000
[20240305_12:19:40.622868]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: RBBM_INT_UNMASKED_STATUS=1 PWR_COL_KEEPALIVE=0
[20240305_12:19:40.622889]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: CP2GMU_STATUS=0 CONTEXT_SWITCH_CNTL=0 AO_SPARE_CNTL=0
[20240305_12:19:40.622961]@0 ------------[ cut here ]------------
[20240305_12:19:40.623004]@0 WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 272 at drivers/gpu/msm/adreno_a6xx_gmu.c:973 a6xx_gmu_wait_for_lowest_idle+0x450/0x490
[20240305_12:19:40.623024]@0 Modules linked in: wlan(O) rmnet_perf(O) machine_dlkm(O) wcd934x_dlkm(O) mbhc_dlkm(O) wcd9360_dlkm(O) swr_ctrl_dlkm(O) wcd9xxx_dlkm(O) tfa9894_dlkm(O) wsa881x_dlkm(O) wcd_core_dlkm(O) stub_dlkm(O) wcd_spi_dlkm(O) hdmi_dlkm(O) swr_dlkm(O) pinctrl_wcd_dlkm(O) usf_dlkm(O) native_dlkm(O) platform_dlkm(O) q6_dlkm(O) adsp_loader_dlkm(O) apr_dlkm(O) q6_notifier_dlkm(O) q6_pdr_dlkm(O) wglink_dlkm(O) msm_11ad_proxy [last unloaded: rmnet_perf]
[20240305_12:19:40.623200]@0 CPU: 0 PID: 272 Comm: kgsl_worker_thr Tainted: G S      W  O    4.14.190-perf+ #1
[20240305_12:19:40.623220]@0 Hardware name: Qualcomm Technologies, Inc. SM8150 V2 PM8150 MTP 18865 19863 14 15 (DT)
[20240305_12:19:40.623243]@0 task: 00000000ead67ef5 task.stack: 000000007e72c1e2
[20240305_12:19:40.623263]@0 pc : a6xx_gmu_wait_for_lowest_idle+0x450/0x490
[20240305_12:19:40.623282]@0 lr : a6xx_gmu_wait_for_lowest_idle+0x44c/0x490
[20240305_12:19:40.623300]@0 sp : ffffff8014783980 pstate : 60c00145
[20240305_12:19:40.623316]@0 x29: ffffff80147839b0 x28: 0000000000000004 
[20240305_12:19:40.623348]@0 x27: 0000000000000002 x26: 0000000000000002 
[20240305_12:19:40.623379]@0 x25: ffffffe2b336e000 x24: 0000000000023b0c 
[20240305_12:19:40.623409]@0 x23: 0000000272d3af12 x22: 0000000272d3aee0 
[20240305_12:19:40.623440]@0 x21: 000000000001f888 x20: 0000000272b38cc6 
[20240305_12:19:40.623471]@0 x19: ffffff8b4a2fac00 x18: ffffff8b4a238000 
[20240305_12:19:40.623502]@0 x17: 0000000000000000 x16: ffffff8b4a45d000 
[20240305_12:19:40.623533]@0 x15: 4c544e435f455241 x14: 0000000000000060 
[20240305_12:19:40.623563]@0 x13: 0000000000000444 x12: 0000000810947aa9 
[20240305_12:19:40.623593]@0 x11: 0000000000000015 x10: 00000000000f4240 
[20240305_12:19:40.623624]@0 x9 : 610bdee29b856c00 x8 : 610bdee29b856c00 
[20240305_12:19:40.623655]@0 x7 : 0000000000000000 x6 : ffffff8b4a45cdaa 
[20240305_12:19:40.623686]@0 x5 : 0000000000000034 x4 : 0000000000000008 
[20240305_12:19:40.623715]@0 x3 : 0000000000000000 x2 : 000000000000006e 
[20240305_12:19:40.623746]@0 x1 : ffffff8b47f48d3c x0 : 00000000ffffff92 
[20240305_12:19:40.623780]@0 
PC: 0xffffff8b48696360:
[20240305_12:19:40.623797]@0 6360  9400632e f9400728 b0009a81 b85ec3a2 91238821 b94013e3 91004100 94006327
[20240305_12:19:40.623885]@0 6380  f9400728 b0009a81 29410be3 91245021 b94007e4 91004100 94006320 12800da0
[20240305_12:19:40.623965]@0 63a0  d4210000 9000dbc9 f85f83a8 f9404529 eb08013f 54000121 a9484ff4 f94023fb
[20240305_12:19:40.624046]@0 63c0  a94757f6 a9465ff8 a94567fa a9437bfd 910243ff d65f03c0 97e0a1aa d503201f
[20240305_12:19:40.624127]@0 
LR: 0xffffff8b4869635c:
[20240305_12:19:40.624142]@0 635c  91004100 9400632e f9400728 b0009a81 b85ec3a2 91238821 b94013e3 91004100
[20240305_12:19:40.624223]@0 637c  94006327 f9400728 b0009a81 29410be3 91245021 b94007e4 91004100 94006320
[20240305_12:19:40.624303]@0 639c  12800da0 d4210000 9000dbc9 f85f83a8 f9404529 eb08013f 54000121 a9484ff4
[20240305_12:19:40.624383]@0 63bc  f94023fb a94757f6 a9465ff8 a94567fa a9437bfd 910243ff d65f03c0 97e0a1aa
[20240305_12:19:40.624464]@0 
SP: 0xffffff8014783940:
[20240305_12:19:40.624480]@0 3940  486963a0 ffffff8b 60c00145 00000000 ffffffd0 ffffff80 499e7914 ffffff8b
[20240305_12:19:40.624560]@0 3960  ffffffff ffffffff 9b856c00 610bdee2 147839b0 ffffff80 486963a0 ffffff8b
[20240305_12:19:40.624638]@0 3980  147839b0 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001
[20240305_12:19:40.624718]@0 39a0  01000000 71000000 9b856c00 610bdee2 14783a10 ffffff80 4865924c ffffff8b
[20240305_12:19:40.624797]@0 
[20240305_12:19:40.624815]@0 Call trace:
[20240305_12:19:40.624834]@0  a6xx_gmu_wait_for_lowest_idle+0x450/0x490
[20240305_12:19:40.624857]@0  gmu_stop+0x34/0xf0
[20240305_12:19:40.624877]@0  gmu_core_stop+0x1c/0x28
[20240305_12:19:40.624901]@0  kgsl_pwrctrl_disable+0x70/0xb8
[20240305_12:19:40.624921]@0  _slumber+0x208/0x2e0
[20240305_12:19:40.624939]@0  kgsl_pwrctrl_change_state+0x234/0x510
[20240305_12:19:40.624962]@0  _adreno_start+0x2b8/0x958
[20240305_12:19:40.624981]@0  adreno_start+0x44/0x78
[20240305_12:19:40.624998]@0  _wake+0xc4/0x3f8
[20240305_12:19:40.625017]@0  kgsl_active_count_get+0x148/0x1e0
[20240305_12:19:40.625039]@0  sendcmd+0xe4/0x508
[20240305_12:19:40.625058]@0  _adreno_dispatcher_issuecmds+0x2a8/0x5b8
[20240305_12:19:40.625076]@0  adreno_dispatcher_work+0x450/0x9d0
[20240305_12:19:40.625101]@0  kthread_worker_fn+0x80/0x168
[20240305_12:19:40.625119]@0  kthread+0x11c/0x130
[20240305_12:19:40.625141]@0  ret_from_fork+0x10/0x1c
[20240305_12:19:40.625158]@0 ---[ end trace 137859bf8ec69b6e ]---
[20240305_12:19:40.625228]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: Failed to stop GMU
[20240305_12:19:40.625690]@0 kgsl kgsl-3d0: |_wake| start failed -110
[20240305_12:19:40.625985]@1 kgsl kgsl-3d0: RB[-1]: gmu fault status 00000001 rb 0000/0000 ib1 0000000000000000/0000 ib2 0000000000000000/0000
[20240305_12:19:40.626077]@0 kgsl kgsl-3d0: |kgsl_iommu_fault_handler| GPU PAGE FAULT: addr = 0 pid= 0 name=unknown
[20240305_12:19:40.626104]@0 kgsl kgsl-3d0: |kgsl_iommu_fault_handler| context=gfx3d_user TTBR0=0x3000273352000 CIDR=0x0 (read translation fault)
[20240305_12:19:40.626129]@0 kgsl kgsl-3d0: |kgsl_iommu_fault_handler| FAULTING BLOCK: CP
[20240305_12:19:40.626178]@0 kgsl kgsl-3d0: ---- nearby memory ----
[20240305_12:19:40.626200]@0 kgsl kgsl-3d0: *EMPTY*
[20240305_12:19:40.626219]@0 kgsl kgsl-3d0:  <- fault @ 00000000
[20240305_12:19:40.626236]@0 kgsl kgsl-3d0: *EMPTY*
[20240305_12:19:40.627643]@1 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: Suspended GMU
[20240305_12:19:40.633654]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: GMU CM3 fault interrupt received
[20240305_12:19:40.742778]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: OOB_set(0x40000000) timed out
[20240305_12:19:40.774568]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: Suspended GMU
[20240305_12:19:40.780103]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: GMU CM3 fault interrupt received
[20240305_12:19:40.882739]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: OOB_set(0x40000000) timed out
[20240305_12:19:40.914491]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: Suspended GMU
[20240305_12:19:40.920147]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: GMU CM3 fault interrupt received
[20240305_12:19:41.022673]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: OOB_set(0x40000000) timed out
[20240305_12:19:41.054826]@1 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: Suspended GMU
[20240305_12:19:41.060742]@0 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: GMU CM3 fault interrupt received
[20240305_12:19:41.162731]@3 platform 2c6a000.qcom,gmu: OOB_set(0x40000000) timed out
[20240305_12:19:41.192733]@3 ------------[ cut here ]------------
[20240305_12:19:41.192774]@3 kernel BUG at drivers/gpu/msm/adreno_dispatch.c:2270!
[20240305_12:19:41.192799]@3 Internal error: Oops - BUG: 0 [#1] PREEMPT SMP
[20240305_12:19:41.192816]@3 Modules linked in: wlan(O) rmnet_perf(O) machine_dlkm(O) wcd934x_dlkm(O) mbhc_dlkm(O) wcd9360_dlkm(O) swr_ctrl_dlkm(O) wcd9xxx_dlkm(O) tfa9894_dlkm(O) wsa881x_dlkm(O) wcd_core_dlkm(O) stub_dlkm(O) wcd_spi_dlkm(O) hdmi_dlkm(O) swr_dlkm(O) pinctrl_wcd_dlkm(O) usf_dlkm(O) native_dlkm(O) platform_dlkm(O) q6_dlkm(O) adsp_loader_dlkm(O) apr_dlkm(O) q6_notifier_dlkm(O) q6_pdr_dlkm(O) wglink_dlkm(O) msm_11ad_proxy [last unloaded: rmnet_perf]
[20240305_12:19:41.192984]@3 Process kgsl_worker_thr (pid: 272, stack limit = 0x000000007e72c1e2)
[20240305_12:19:41.193004]@3 CPU: 3 PID: 272 Comm: kgsl_worker_thr Tainted: G S      W  O    4.14.190-perf+ #1
[20240305_12:19:41.193018]@3 Hardware name: Qualcomm Technologies, Inc. SM8150 V2 PM8150 MTP 18865 19863 14 15 (DT)
[20240305_12:19:41.193033]@3 task: 00000000ead67ef5 task.stack: 000000007e72c1e2
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this error? Or why might this be happening?

Comment: The error you are showing is not the original error. After failing it attempts to reset, but the reset fails, so it bugs. https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm.git/+/android-msm-hammerhead-3.4-marshmallow-mr3/drivers/gpu/msm/adreno_dispatch.c#1186

Comment: The strangest thing for me is that I have had this smartphone for several years and for several of these years I have been using the same version of Android, the same applications. There was no such problem before. I assume this bug appeared with the update of some Google system applications?

Comment: Could you post this same question in [Android Enthusiast](https://android.stackexchange.com/) site, as the question is not about programming.